# Пропустить несуществующее значение при переборе JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть `JSON`, который я получаю с `firebase`. Дальше с помощью цикла `for(){}` перебираю значения для вывода в таблицу. Но, когда появляется несуществующее значение, появляется ошибка.

Как мне пропустить это значение и продолжить перебор и вывод значений?

JSON

```
{
  "avto_7_2017" : {
    "avto1" : {
      "avto" : 1,
      "number" : "145",
      "vladelec" : "Ivanov"
    },
    "avto2" : {
      "avto" : 2,
      "number" : "50",
      "vladelec" : "Sydorov"
    },
    "avto5" : {
      "avto" : 5,
      "number" : "60",
      "vladelec" : "Petrenko"
    }
  }
}
```

Вот такая таблица должна получиться

```
Авто    Номер     Владелец
1       145       Ivanov
2       50        Sydorov
3
4
5       60        Petrenko
```

Первые два значения заполняются с помощью цикла `for(){}` дальше т.к значений нет ошибка `jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'avto' of undefined`

Comment: Не совсем понятно о чем идет речь, нужно уточнение. Желательно пример кода.

Comment: покажи как именно ты перебираешь

Answer (score 0):

Проверку на несуществующее значение можно сделать с помощью оператора [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

```js
let object = {
    'avto1': {
        'avto': 1,
        'number': '145',
        'vladelec': 'Ivanov'
    },
    'avto2': {
        'avto': 2,
        'number': '50',
        'vladelec': 'Sydorov'
    },
    'avto5': {
        'avto': 5,
        'number': '60',
        'vladelec': 'Petrenko'
    }
};

const defaulAvto = {
    'avto': '',
    'number': '',
    'vladelec': ''
};

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
    let key = 'avto' + i;
    let avto = key in object ? object[key] : defaulAvto;
    $('tbody').append(
        `<tr>
            <td>${i}</td>
            <td>${avto.number}</td>
            <td>${avto.vladelec}</td>
        </tr>`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Авто</td>
        <td>Номер</td>
        <td>Владелец</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```